# isochoric first-order transition

Tags: phase-transition

I wonder how can we classify a phase transition that occurs (at constant volume) without any discontinuity in pressure but with a step in energy? Is it still a first order transition?

Comment: Have a look at the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition) article. In modern classification it is the presence of latent heat that makes it first order.

Comment: First order phase transitions require a volume change.